# Rails 3 integrate image in a view template

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, image, view

I'm locked with a stupid issue in Rails 3... In fact, I'm building the css to design my application and I've a div called banner in which I want to integrate a logo (that is a png file). So I'm working on the views/layouts/application.html.erb.

I've put the image.png into the public/images folder.

In my css I use:

```
background-image: url("images/rails.png");
```

And nothing displays... It drives me nuts. Is there someone to help me with this basic question? Does it has something to do with Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a forward / `background-image: url("/images/rails.png");`

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause of the problem is the relative URL you've entered.

If the image is embedded on a page with URL `/articles/1/` your browser will fetch the image from `/articles/1/images/rails.png` instead of `/images/rails.png`.

If you prepend the resource with a slash, it will probably work:

```
background-image: url(/images/rails.png);
```

BTW I think it is a good idea to read the [Rails Assets Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), because the place for static images is no longer the `public` directory.